# Load multiple files into dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, io, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to load multiple files as one dataframe? Normally, if I have one file to load, I will call for example:

```
file1 = "/a/b/c/folder/file1.csv"
dc = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', inferschema='true').load(file1)
```

But I want to load all files under the folder `/a/b/c/folder/*.csv`.

Comment: What happens if you try `dc = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', inferschema='true').load("a/b/c/folder/*.csv")` Does it throw an error? Does it work?

Comment: I get a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18002" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', inferschema='true').load(folder)` works. Previously I got error is because I am ready compressed files, and they are oversized compared with the memory